# $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})\cap S^1$ is dense in $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove (or disprove) that $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})\cap S^1$ is dense in $S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at the origin, and we want to use the definition of dense subset as the following: for $A\subset B\subset X$, $A$ is dense in $B$ if for every open set $O\subset X$, $O\cap B\neq\varnothing\implies O\cap A\neq\varnothing$. I am also trying to use the fact that it is sufficient to show the above condition for every open ball in $S^1$ by using the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, moving from 'grids' to a circle is nontrivial to me. For instance, to satisfy the condition
$$(x,y)\in B_\epsilon((a,b))$$
where $(x,y)$ is the point we are looking for and $B_\epsilon((a,b))$ is a ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at a point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} \cap S^1$, by direct substitution of the definition of $S^1$, it is sufficient to satisfy
$$r^2-\epsilon^2/2<ax+by.$$
However, to show that there are such $(x,y)$ that satisfy this condition and $x^2+y^2=1$ simultaneously seems particularly nontrivial for me.

Would there be a better way to show that $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})\cap S^1$ is dense in $S^1$?

Comment: Something to ponder is that $S^1$ itself is of utmost importance to the problem. If you replaced $x^2+y^2=1$ with $x^4+y^4=1$, or almost any other equation in two variables of degree at least $5$ (and very many cases starting from degree $3$), then there would only be a few points on the curve with rational coordinates. You could consider what the coordinates of the two points in the intersection of $S^1$ with a line of rational slope can be.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097901/are-the-rationals-on-a-unit-circle-dense) may help.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for lots of rational solutions to $p^2 + q^2 = 1$, which after clearing out the denominators can be turned into integer solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Does that help?

Concrete example: $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$, so $(\frac{3}{5})^2 + (\frac{4}{5})^2 = 1$.

Comment: Not much of a help, I would say.

Comment: Even with Euclid's formula for generating Pythagorean triples?